# Divide dataframe into batches Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to run a set of transformations on batches of hours of the dataframe. And the number of hours should be parameterized so it could be changed - for example, run transformations on 3 hours of dataframe, then next 2 hours. In such a way, there should be a step with a parameterized number of hours for each transformation.

The signature of the transformation looks like this:

```
def transform(wordsFeed: DataFrame)(filesFeed: DataFrame): Unit
```

So I want to do this division into batches and then call a transform on this datafeed. But I can't use groupBy as it would change dataframe into grouped dataset while I need to preserve all the columns in the schema. How can I do that?

```
val groupedDf = df.srcHours.groupBy($"event_ts")
transform(keywords)(groupedDf)
```

Data schema looks like this:

```
root
 |-- date_time: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- user_id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- order_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- description: string (nullable = true)
 |-- hashed_user_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- event_date: date (nullable = true)
 |-- event_ts: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- event_hour: long (nullable = true)
```

The main reason to introduce this batching is that there's too much data to process at once.
Note: I still want to use batch data processing and not streaming in this case

Comment: Use `bucketizer` to assign a bucket id to the timestamps, and then divide your dataframe using the bucket id (e.g.`val df2 = df.filter("bucketid = 3")`) https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#bucketizer

Comment: I don't really need mllib plus I want to process all the buckets I just want to perform processing batch by batch